# Why I go error_404.php errors in codeigniter when upload to hosting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-config

my website doesn't work when i upload to hosting but it is work in localhost.
and when I try to access url it alwasy show me **ERROR - 12-01-14 06:33:25 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index** (log file) and I got errors.

Here is my hosting user name and password
Access the Control Panel here:

- **https://cp.supremecenter300.com**
- **Client ID: 142606**
- **Login: hengsopheak**
- **Password: 2142885**

  defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  function __autoload($classname) {
      if (strpos($classname, 'CI_') !== 0) {
          $file = APPPATH . 'libraries/' . $classname . '.php';
          if (file_exists($file)) {
              @include_once($file);
          }
      }
  }

  $config['base_url'] = '';

  $config['index_page'] = '';

  $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';

  $config['url_suffix'] = '';

  $config['language'] = 'english';

  $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

  $config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

  $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

  $config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;

  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-';

  $config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
  $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
  $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
  $config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
  $config['directory_trigger'] = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

  $config['log_threshold'] = 4;

  $config['log_path'] = '';

  $config['log_file_extension'] = 'php';

  $config['log_date_format'] = 'm-d-y H:i:s';

  $config['error_views_path'] = 'application/views/errors';

  $config['cache_path'] = '';

  $config['encryption_key'] = 'sdfasdfasdfasdfadf';

  $config['sess_driver'] = 'cookie';
  $config['sess_valid_drivers'] = array();
  $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
  $config['sess_expiration'] = 7720;
  $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
  $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
  $config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
  $config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
  $config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
  $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
  $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

  $config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
  $config['cookie_domain'] = 'vtrashop.com/';
  $config['cookie_path'] = '/';
  $config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
  $config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;

and Router

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page';
$route['cat/(:num)'] = 'cat/index/$1/$2/$3';
$route['detail/(:num)'] = 'detail/index/$1/$2';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

In Controller file name:page Class name: Page.

```
<?php

Class Page extends Frontend_controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index() {

         $this->data['subview'] = 'page';
        $this->load->view('_main_layout', $this->data);
        }
?>
```

and .htaccess

```
# Set PHP Time Zone:
#SetEnv TZ America/New_York
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#Option +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|pages|video|images|social|style|sliderengine|bar|robots\.text)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

I get only this messages **Message: include(): Failed opening 'application/views/errorshtml/error_404.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\php\pear')**

How can I do now

Comment: never share your hosting details remove from the question

Comment: I don't care about security now I want it work only ?

Comment: this error is showing becoz you give wrong path your path is application/views/errors/html/error_404.php

Comment: Not this one I change it more and more time I try 2weeks but still not wrok

Comment: My boos nearly kill me now

Comment: Now I got this The page you requested was not found. although all controller is conrrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most times this error is happening because of file naming problems. I think you are using a Linux hosting. So I also faced to the same problem and finally I found the solution we cannot use file names with UPPERCASE characters.

**Example**

If we have a controller called my_controller the file name is should be like this my_controller.php and don't use UPPERCASE characters like this My_Controller.php, myController.php for the file name.

Comment: so I have change all my controller to lowercase right?

Comment: $Chamath,

How about CI should I change ti ci_controller too? right

Comment: No change only file names those controllers you have created.

Comment: If you're a newbie to CI, then renaming your Controller classes to lowercase should fix it. As this is most likely the case when switching from localhost to an online hosting environment.